# Google apps script to pull text from website

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a shell script I made to pull the amount of players listed on a game website for example. I took the number and added a timestamp and put it on google spreadsheets so I could make a graph over time to track data. The only problem is to run that, I need to keep my computer on, I'm going to guess you can do this with a google script of some kind but I have no idea how to begin doing that.

The shell script I used was:

```
 wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null \
| grep PlayerCount \
| head -1l \
| sed 's/^[^>]*>//' \
| sed "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%m\/%d\/%Y %H:%M:%S')/" \
| cut -d">" -f 3,4 \
| sed 's/<\/span>//' \
| sed 's/,//' \
| awk '{printf "%s %s,%s,%s\n", $3, $4, $1, $2}'
```

Output example: `11/21/2012 01:02:22,52833,people`

What I wanted was to have it auto pull that number and store it on a cell every 2 minutes for example. But I am not sure how easy it is or where to begin.

Then it would look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp2rJ.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible that if you may hit a quota limitation when doing this. But here's how I'd do it.

```js
function pullRuneScape() {
  var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://runescape.com/title.ws').getContentText();
  var number = page.match(/PlayerCount.*>([0-9,]+)</)[1];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').appendRow([new Date(), number]);
}
```

Open a Google Spreadsheet, then click the menu Tools > Script Editor, paste the above code and save. Still on the script editor, click Resources > Current script's triggers. Then set this function to run on a time-driven trigger.

Comment: I like this. Will be testing it now to see if I have any questions but so far I don't. What language is this written in and how would I learn about these functions? And do you know what the quota limit is?

Comment: @Aaron You can start learning Google Apps script @ https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ Google Apps uses Javascript which run on Google's server

Comment: @Henrique Abreu Does this do military time? Because it might screw up the graph since I can't make a line graph with AM and PM on there.

Comment: @Aaron Apps Script is a "server-side" javascript with it's own libraries. Folow the link Waqar posted to learn more. The time on the spreadsheet is a "datetime" value (a number underneath). How it's going to display is up to your formatting. If you want to put a text on the spreadsheet we can certainly change the code.

Comment: It seems to be using Military time so I have no issues anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UrlFetch App in Apps Script to fetch the content of the page and that can be parsed using regular expressions to get the player count.
Here is a little code which I tried. It uses YQL with Apps Script to avoid regular expression parsing.

```
function retreiveOnlineUsers(){
  var query = 'select * from html where url="http://runescape.com/title.ws" and xpath=\'//div[@id="PlayerCount"]/p[1]/span\'&format=json';
  var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=';
  var queryURL = yql+encodeURI(query);
  var jsonString = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryURL).getContentText();
  var json = Utilities.jsonParse(jsonString);
  var palyerCount = json.query.results.span;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  l = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(l+1, 1, 1, 3).setValues([[new Date(), palyerCount, 'people']]);
}
```

References:

- [YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22http://runescape.com/title.ws%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath=%27//div%5B@id=%22PlayerCount%22%5D/p%5B1%5D/span%27)
- [UrlFetch Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlfetch)

This script is tested and working correctly. Here are the steps to follow to make it working with your spreadsheet.

1. Create a new empty Spreadsheet and save it with a name
2. Open the Script Editor by clicking on the 'Tools' menu, then select 'Script editor...'.
3. Copy and paste the following script
4. Save the Script
5. Select the function retreiveOnlineUsers in the function combo box and click "Run", this will populate a row in your sheet.
6. Now you can schedule this script to run through [time driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers).

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to set yours up, if you see this and would be willing to give some steps that would be nice. I will update my message if I figure it out though.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I can not make it simpler anymore, please give some time to the tutorials to understand the basics.

Comment: Thank you for updating it. What is: "It uses YQL with Apps Script to avoid regular expression parsing."  ?

Comment: It means that instead of fetching the runescape site directly he calls another site (YQL), that parses the site for you and returns a JSON with the result. JSON are natural on javascript and much easier to work and less prone to problems then parsing like we did (your seds and greps and my js regex).